# How do you calculate the standard deviation on a multiplicative scale for a distribution that has been transformed logarithmically?

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation, logarithm

I know the value for the 16% quartile, so I know the additive deviation for the given distribution. How do I find the deviation of the log of the given distribution on a multiplicative scale?

Comment: Can you provide more detail Justin?

Comment: What else do you know about the distribution apart from its 16th percentile (which is what i assume you mean by "16% quartile")?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to something like the estimated coefficients in a logistic regression. These are the log-odds. The estimates usually have a standard error and symmetrical confidence interval.

For example lets say an estimated log odds is 2 with an SE of 0.5 and 95% CI of 1.02 to 2.98. The odds ratio you calculate as exp(2) = 7.4.  To estimate a "balanced" 95% confidence interval for the odds ratio exponentiate both ends of the 95% CI on the linear scale, viz. exp(1.02) to exp(2.98) gives a 95% CI of 2.8 to 19.7. You could do the same with both ends of the SD or SE interval: exp(1.5) to exp(2.5) gives 4.5 to 12.2 which we might describe as a 68% confidence interval about the mean odds ratio of 7.4.

Note this is not the same as the standard deviation of a "transformed" distribution, ([eg the log-normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)), which is defined on the new scale and is symmetrical on that scale even if the distribution is skew.